# Why do tuples become strings after saving to csv and reloading the dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, namedtuple

```py
import pandas as pd
from random import random
from collections import namedtuple

Smoker    = namedtuple("Smoker", ["Female","Male"])
Nonsmoker = namedtuple("Nonsmoker", ["Female","Male"])

DF = dict() 
DF["A"] = [(Smoker(random(),random()), Nonsmoker(random(),random())) for t in range(3)]
DF["B"] = [(Smoker(random(),random()), Nonsmoker(random(),random())) for t in range(3)]
DF = pd.DataFrame(DF, index=["t="+str(t+1) for t in range(3)])
```

I have this dataframe, each of whose cells is **a tuple of two namedtuples**. After I saved it to csv file and reloaded it, the printed-out looked the same, but each cell became a **string**. How did it happen? What should I do to obtain the same dataframe every time?

```py
DF.to_csv("results.csv", index_label=False)
df = pd.read_csv('results.csv', index_col=0)

print(df)

for a,b in zip(df.A,df.B):
    print(type(a),type(b))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is expected behaviour. Since `csv` is text-base, when you save `object` dtype to `csv`, the natural way is to use the string representation. So `tuple((1,2))` becomes `"(1,2)"`.

Now, when you read back `csv` file, the natural and safe way to interpret `"(1,2)"` is of course the string `'(1,2)'` because Pandas doesn't have an engine to parse tuple-valued columns.

**TLDR**, that's normal and expected behaviour. If you want to save and load your data with `object` dtype, you should use binary format such as `to_pickle` and `from_pickle` methods.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between .pkl and .p file?

Comment: I'm not so sure. My guess is just different conventions of naming the same thing. Much like `.jpg` and `.jpeg`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to get a tuple while reading the csv is to use `converters`

**Ex:**

```
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('results.csv', index_col=0, converters={"A": ast.literal_eval, 
                                                         "B": ast.literal_eval})
```

Comment: I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
from that.